# Why is my toFixed() function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, number-formatting

Here's the relevant code.  I've confirmed with the alert that the correct number is saved, it's just not being changed to 2 decimal places.

```
if ($(this).attr('name') == 'time') {
    var value = $(this).val();
    parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
    alert(value);
    editEntry.time = value;
}
```

Comment: Note: .toFixed(x) will return a string object

Answer (score 227, accepted):

You're not assigning the parsed float back to your value var:

```
value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
```

should fix things up.

Comment: Can't you also just multiply it by 1?

Comment: I think it should be value = parseFloat(value.toFixed(2)); That is, unless you want a string for the value. ToFixed returns a string, doing the toFixed inside will keep the value a number.

Comment: the value is being assigned to an input form field, which is ALWAYS a string.

Comment: @dchin makes a valid point... you should do it this way if you need a number returned..

Comment: @dchin if you want trailing 0's to a certain place, for example to the hundredths or thousandths, you do want it as a string to retain that many digits.  For example a counter will look more stable if the number of digits does not change.  parseFloat would most likely cause you to lose your trailing digits if you leave it as a number, undoing the "3 decimal place" placeholder 0 digits, right?

Answer (score 9):

I tried function toFixed(2) many times. Every time console shows "toFixed() is not a function".

but how I resolved is By using Math.round()

eg:

```
if ($(this).attr('name') == 'time') {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    value = Math.round(value*100)/100; // 10 defines 1 decimals, 100 for 2, 1000 for 3
    alert(value);
}
```

this thing surely works for me and it might help you guys too...

Answer (score 3):

Your value must not be an integer so add 0 to convert your value into integer and then toFixed() will work.

Answer (score 2):

Before rounding of the decimal values to 2 number.
Convert the value into number simple like below

```
value = Number(value).toFixed(2);
```

This should fix things.

Answer (score 1):

Example simple (worked):

```
var a=Number.parseFloat($("#budget_project").val()); // from input field
var b=Number.parseFloat(html); // from ajax
var c=a-b;
$("#result").html(c.toFixed(2)); // put to id='result' (div or others)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion data is response[25] and follow the below steps.

```
var i = parseFloat(response[25]).toFixed(2)
console.log(i)//-6527.34
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("EDTVALOR").addEventListener("change", function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(",", ".");
  this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
  if (this.value < 0) {
    this.value = 0;
  }
  this.value = this.value.replace(".", ",");
  this.value = this.value.replace("NaN", "0");
});
```

Comment: "The specified value "0,01" cannot be parsed, or is out of range."