# javascript syntax error (limit 2 decimal)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i made this:

```
document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value.replace(".", ",").toFixed(2)
```

I'm trying to limit a value to two decimal places.

But with `.toFixed(2)` my script does not work, what am I doing wrong?

complete code:

```
<script>

  var jq111 = jQuery.noConflict();

   jq111(function(){

   jq111('#_regular_price').on('input', function(){

   document.getElementsByName("duel-cost")[0].value = document.getElementsByName("_regular_price")[0].value.replace(",", ".");

   if(jq111("#prized").val().length > 1) {
    var discount = document.getElementsByName("discount")[0].value;
    var cost = document.getElementsByName("duel-cost")[0].value;
     document.getElementsByName("_sale_price")[0].value = cost - (cost * (discount / 100));
    }
  })
});
```

```
<script>

 function updateInput(){

  document.getElementsByName("duel-cost")[0].value = document.getElementsByName("_regular_price")[0].value.replace(",", ".");

   var discount = document.getElementsByName("discount")[0].value;

   var cost = document.getElementsByName("duel-cost")[0].value;

   document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value = cost - (cost * (discount / 100));

   document.getElementsByName("_sale_price")[0].value = document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value.replace(".", ",").toFixed(2);

}

</script>
```

New:

```
 var element = document.getElementsByName("price")[0];

 element.value = parseFloat(element.value.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');

 document.getElementsByName("_sale_price")[0].value = element;
```

Comment: It would help if you elaborated on "breaks my script". You've given valid syntax, so there's something else going on.

Comment: now i paste my full code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why is my toFixed() function not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937251/why-is-my-tofixed-function-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

Strings don't have a `toFixed` method; numbers do. The `value` of an input is a string, which is something you've relied on when calling `replace` on it.

If `value` contains a valid number by JavaScript's rules, you could do this:

```
var element = document.getElementsByName("price")[0];
element.value = parseFloat(element.value).toFixed(2);
```

<s>I don't know what you were trying to do with the `replace`, so I've left that out.</s> Your full code makes more sense. In your original, you were replacing `.` with `,`. But your full code replaces `,` with `.`, which makes sense, so:

```
var element = document.getElementsByName("price")[0];
element.value = parseFloat(element.value.replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
```

Note how I'm putting the `,` back.

You might want to handle the use of `.` as a thousands separator, too. Doing that properly is a bit complex, but we could just remove them:

```
var element = document.getElementsByName("price")[0];
element.value = parseFloat(element.value.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
```

Comment: i add a new version on my post called "new". The input say: [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: @EugenioSegala: Then you're missing `.value` somewhere. *Edit:* Yes, at the end. Remember, `element` is the **element**, `element.value` is its `value` property.