# KnockoutJS script creating issues with commaseparated numeric values

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am attempting to bind together a javascript function, but I keep getting problems with the decimal numeric values being converted automatically (53.000 is converted to 53000) when binding. Below is the example of what I am attempting to achieve;

```
<script data-bind="text: 'getNewValue(Price ',' + VAT + ');'"></script>
```

Where VAT is 53.000 and Price is 378.

I have tried appending .toFixed(2) without success like so;

```
<script data-bind="text: 'getNewValue(Price.toFixed(2) ',' + VAT.toFixed(2) + ');'"></script>
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

/Peter

Comment: what format is the value? also what happens in the getNewValue function? The toFixed(2) should usually give a correct decimal number

Comment: The number has the exact format "53.000" as I wrote in the description. The getNewValue function functionality does not matter, as I simply need to get the correct value into the getNewValue function. I need for the function "getnewValue" to get the values "53,00" as well as "378". Makes sense?

Comment: you can call it without the single quotation marks then. just call the function as i mentioned in the answer below, if you need to pass the variables as 2 variables just remove the +','+ and add a comma

Comment: this would be the typical case for an extender, or a custom function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16023748/4845566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In knockout.js you can define the function directly in the data-bind like this:

```
<script data-bind="text: getNewValue(Price.toFixed(2) + ',' + VAT.toFixed(2));"></script>
```

This would call your getNewValue function with both values decimal fixed to 2 in one variable

If you just want a concatenation of those 2 values, you can also do it directly in the databind like this:

```
<script data-bind="text: Price.toFixed(2) + ', ' + VAT.toFixed(2);"></script>
```

This would result in:
53.00, 378.00

Comment: The problem is that I get Price.toFixed is not a function when doing just that. As I mentioned, I have already tried doing toFixed(2)

Comment: Message: Price.toFixed is not a function
    at eval (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout-2.3.0.debug.js:2000), <anonymous>:3:204)
    at ko.bindingProvider.parseBindingsString (knockout-2.3.0.debug.js:1978)
    at ko.bindingProvider.getBindings (knockout-2.3.0.debug.js:1960)
    at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout-2.3.0.debug.js:2123)
    at evaluateImmediate (knockout-2.3.0.debug.js:1270)...

Comment: You haven't mentioned that you get this error. This looks to me like the price value is not of the type number. try: parseFloat(Price).toFixed(2) as mentioned in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937251/why-is-my-tofixed-function-not-working

Comment: I juuust realized this simple thing. Thank you for pointing out the obvious!

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this originally to handle phone numbers but it seems to work well for currency. (Note: I am using USD here). With this subscribable computed, you just append it to any currency element and it will display correctly as a currency, but you retain the value as a float/int. This makes it easier to use it in calculations throughout the view model.

```js
function ToAmount() {
  return ko.computed({
    read: function() {
      var num = parseFloat(ko.unwrap(this));
      return this() ? "$" + num.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") : "$0.00";
    },
    write: function(_amount) {
      this(_amount);
      this.notifySubscribers();
    },
    owner: this,
  }).extend({
    notify: 'always'
  });
}
ko.subscribable.fn.ToAmount = ToAmount;

function vm() {
  var self = this;

  self.Money = ko.observable(12.345);
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="value: Money.ToAmount()">
```

Comment: Thank you for great feedback!